# loading videos in loop...always the firist video is shown - jquery issue?

Tags: php, jquery, jwplayer

I have page where I load different videos.I use jw player as player if that means something. And my problem is quite wired...JW player play only the first video. No matter which link I click, always the first video has been played.

If I see my source code (executed html), videos are loaded correctly, that is img1, link to video1.flw, img2 link to video2.flw...and so on. However, no matter which link I click, only the first video is played.

Anyone can figure out why this may happen???

Here is the code that is relevant for the videos:

I have this code in the header:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/basic.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

And this is the code where the video is placed:

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
<a href='#' class='basic'>
<img src="backOffice/backOfficeImages/<?php echo $r[instrument_image]; ?>" alt="" width="300" height="410" />
</a> 
</div>

<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">  
<!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE -->
<div id="<?php echo $i;?>">JW Player goes here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("<?php echo $i;?>").setup({ 
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
autostart:true,
file: "backOffice/videos/instruments/<?php echo $r[instrument_video]; ?>",
height: 360,
width: 640
});
</script>
<!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->   
</div>
<!-- preload the images -->
<div style='display:none'>
<img src='images/x.png' alt='' />
</div>

<?php
$i++;
?>
```

The $i varable is set on 0 above the while loop in which this code is. Please note that even in the same loop, images are displayed correctly, in the source code videos are correct (video1, video2, video3...) but only the first video is played, no metter which image you click.

Anyone can help??

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything that tells each link to open a **specific** Modal - I would imagine it's just defaulting to the first one each time.

It all depends on what you have inside of js/jquery.simplemodal.js and js/basic.js (i.e. the code that must be hooking the links up).

I would be expecting to see something that includes the index (0,1,2,3) inside of the link AND the modal - you can then use this to bind link3 to modal3.

Example (but again I need more info on how you are setting up the links for a working answer):

```
<div id='basic-modal' data-index="<?php echo $i;?>">
  ...
</div>


<div id="basic-modal-content" data-index="<?php echo $i;?>">  
  ...
</div>
```

I would then imagine code like this somewhere inside of basic.js (or where the links get hooked up):

```
// hook up the video links to launch the correct modal
$('div#basic-modal').bind('click', function() {

    // grab the index of the link that was clicked
    var linkIndex = $(this).attr('data-index');

    // get a reference to the corresponding modal
    var modal = $('div#basic-modal-content[data-index="' + linkIndex + '"]');

    // use whatever code you need to show the modal window
    modal.show();
});
```

Again - the basic idea is that each link must have some kind of idea as to what window it should be launching and when the link is clicked it used this to get a reference to the correct video modal.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    

jQuery(function ($) {
 // Load dialog on page load
 //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

 // Load dialog on click
 $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
  $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

  return false;
 });
});

}) Here is the code of basic.js

Comment: you nailed it mate. thanks a ton. you save my day with this help. cheeres, zoran